# Multiple data sets in dataform per GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I have just spun up a dataform project that is connected to a google cloud project. My question is, how do i go about formatting dataform to allow for multiple datasets which each contsain their own bespoke sql code?

example structure:

```
dataset 1
 sql_1
 sql_2
 sql_3

dataset 2
 sql_1
 sql_2
 sql_3
```

from what i have read so far, can i only interact with one dataset at a time?

The `dataform.json` file allows me to set the following:

```
{
  "defaultSchema": "test_datasets",
  "assertionSchema": "dataform_assertions",
  "warehouse": "bigquery",
  "defaultDatabase": "project_name",
  "defaultLocation": "EU"
}
```

However if we have more than one dataset in a project, do i need to alter the json file to set another data set? Or is there a better way to deal with gcp projects with multple datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, specify a schema in the `config` block by adding the kv pair: `schema: "your-schema-name"`. Refer here for more: https://docs.dataform.co/guides/datasets/publish#overriding-a-datasets-schema-or-name .

Answer (score 0):

you could(maybe should) always add dataset name when you refer to a table.
${ref("myDataset", "myTable")}, hope it helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
${ref({"name": "sql_1", "schema": "dataset_1"})
```